# Para que serve o csrf_token presente no arquivo de layout do Laravel?

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, token-ajax

Estou ciente de que para submeter um formulário no Laravel, é preciso adicionar um csrf_field, ou declarar que a rota deve ignorar está proteção. Porém, no arquivo de layout existe as seguintes ocorrências:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

...

<script>
    window.Laravel = {!! json_encode([
        'csrfToken' => csrf_token(),
    ]) !!};
</script>
```

Para que são utilizados estes blocos citados acima?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Isso destina-se mais especificamente a formulários do tipo `AJAX`. É basicamente pegar o `token` e incluí-lo nos cabeçalhos para quando você enviar uma solicitação via `AJAX`.

O `Laravel` gera automaticamente um `token CSRF` para cada sessão de usuário ativa gerenciada pelo aplicativo. Esse `token` é usado para verificar se o usuário autenticado é aquele que realmente faz os pedidos para o aplicativo.

Além de verificar o `token CSRF` como um parâmetro POST, o middleware `VerifyCsrfToken` também verifica o cabeçalho da solicitação (`X-CSRF-TOKEN`). Por isso a  existência dessa `metatag`.

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Então, uma vez que se criou a metatag, você pode instruir uma biblioteca como `jQuery` para adicionar automaticamente o `token` a todos os cabeçalhos de solicitação. Isso fornece proteção `CSRF` simples e conveniente para suas aplicações baseadas em AJAX:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
```

Comment: Agora compreendi a importância e funcionamento deste elemento. Obrigado.

Answer (score -6):

Para impedir solicitação mal intencionadas de outros sites, ou seja para proteger seu sites de ataques externos.

Comment: Isso é automático, ou ainda é preciso implementar algum uso para este token?