# O que são CSRF Tokens e por que são fundamentais nos formulários?

Tags: php, laravel

Comecei a mexer agora com Laravel e queria saber o que é *token* que é fundamental nos formulários

```
<form action="/contato" method="POST">
  {{csrf_field()}} 
  <label>Nome</label>
  <input type="text" name="nome" placeholder="Nome/Post">
  <button>enviar</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Para que serve o csrf\_token presente no arquivo de layout do Laravel?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/187017/para-que-serve-o-csrf-token-presente-no-arquivo-de-layout-do-laravel)

Comment: Quero ressaltar que a resposta linkada na pergunta que o @BoiProgramador esta errada, não tem NADA HAVER COM AJAX, o CSRF é para ajudar evitar formulários vindos de outros sites executarem requisições em seu site, no entanto o CSRF não é nem de longe uma técnica infalivel, ao contrário, é bem fácil burlar ela, é mais garantido usar um sistema semelhante ao reCaptcha (existem outros), o CSRF é apenas custoso ao seu site em laravel (laravel já é desastroso em performance por si só) e não será seguro, só evitaria ataques vindo de coisas criadas por quem não tem experiencia.